# Access a Label placed inside a ContentView inside a ResourceDictionary

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, resourcedictionary, content-pages

I have below XAML which contains ContentView inside my main XAML.

I want to know how can I access the **LabelPushNotificationPrice** to change the Text?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:SyncfusionBusyIndicator="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.SfBusyIndicator.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfBusyIndicator.XForms"
x:Class="ZayedAlKhair.InitiativeDetails"
xmlns:SyncfusionPopup="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.XForms.PopupLayout;assembly=Syncfusion.SfPopupLayout.XForms"
Title="زايد الخير">
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="PushNotificationsViewTemplate">
            <ContentView BackgroundColor="White" x:Name="PushNotificationsContentView">
                <StackLayout Padding="15">
                    <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="End" Text="هذه الخدمة تمكنكم من إرسال تنبيهات الهواتف الذكية لجميع مشتركي تطبيق زايد الخير وهي أفضل خدمة لتصل مبادرتكم لآلاف المشتركين" HeightRequest="90" WidthRequest="100" />
                    <Label x:Name="**LabelPushNotificationPrice**" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" Text="سعر الخدمة : 499 دولار" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="100" />                        
                    <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="End" Text="مدة الترويج : مرة واحدة لكل مبادرة" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="100" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ContentView>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="PromoteViewTemplate">
            <ContentView BackgroundColor="White" x:Name="PromoteContentView">
                <StackLayout Padding="15">
                    <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="End" Text="هذه الخدمة ستجعل مبادرتكم مميزة باللون الأحمر ودائما في أعلى القائمة ليتمكن كل مستخدمي التطبيق من التعرف عليها والتفاعل معها" HeightRequest="90" WidthRequest="100" />
                    <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="End" Text="سعر الخدمة : 99 دولار" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="100" />                        
                    <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="End" Text="مدة التمييز : 30 يوما" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="100" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ContentView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<ContentPage.Content>
<Grid Padding="10" x:Name="GridInitiativeDetails">
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Answer (score 1):

The preferred way is to use [DataBindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-binding-basics), example:

```
<Label HorizontalTextAlignment="End" Text="{Binding LabelPushNotificationPrice}" />
```

This way you can seamlessly update the value of the `Label` bound to your `ViewModel`. The point is to separate UI layer from your BL layer and usually we use `MVVM` rather than `MVC` in Xamarin.Forms. [The official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm) is nicely covering this topic and there are free e-books like [Enterprise Application Patterns using Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/) that I recommend to read additionally.

P.S.: Please note that setting a fixed Height & Width on UI controls may break your UX experience on screens with different sizes.

Comment: does this mean it is not possible to have access to the label and its properties without binding? for example .IsVisible or .TextColr, etc....

Comment: Not sure about "not possible", but it gets very tricky without data bindings.

Comment: How can I bind it please?

I tried this but it’s not showing any value and no error:

public class BannerAds {     public double ad_price { get; set; } }

Comment: HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(“url_here”);  if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {     var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();     var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BannerAds>>(data);     ObservableCollection<BannerAds> trends = new ObservableCollection<BannerAds>(result);     this.BindingContext = trends; }

Comment: and in the XAML:

<Label x:Name="LabelPushNotificationPrice" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" Text="{Binding ad_price}" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="100" />

Comment: Please don't share your code in comments, it is very hard to follow. Sounds like you forgot to set the BindingContext of the page to your ViewModel. Also, your ViewModel should implement INotifyPropertyChanged. In my answer I provided you links to official documentation where this topic is fully covered.